# What chip to convert 0-5V from sensor to pwm 0-100%

Tags: integrated-circuit, adc, pwm

I need your recommendation guys.
Requirements:

- static frequency of about 0.1-1Mhz,
- input: voltage of 0-5V,
- output: PWM with duty ratio of 0-100%, standalone chip - no
  additional active
- components required (internal clock etc)
- low cost preferably

I was looking in some shops but couldn't find anything. What I could find were A/D chips without regular output instead it had special interface I2C or other. Also I found U/f converters but I want static frequency with variable duty cycle.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the output voltage and current?

Comment: 3.3V, current up to few mA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single device solution, the [LTC6992](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc6992-1.html) is a decent choice. There's a couple variants depending on required duty cycle range, so make sure you pick the right variant for your application.

If that doesn't work for your needs, you might need to consider building it up yourself out of some discrete parts. There are many examples out there based around a 555 timer for doing voltage to duty cycle conversion.